# Customize TextInput Label of the react-native-paper in the case of React Native Web

Tags: react-native, styled-components, react-native-web, react-native-paper

I'm working with the React Native Web and React Native Paper library with Styled Components. Basically I would like to customize the TextInput inner components: Label and *html input*

The questions are: 
1) How to change Label styles? eg. width\size\color, etc. ?
2) How to change *html input* styles? 
 I want to set `outline: none` to prevent the blue border show on focus in the case of browser. 
I understand that in the case of native we don't have `html` and the native-web transpiles it.

And I can't understand how to *catch* the nested label component to change its styles. Because I want to show *gray* label when non-filled, *violet* when filled and the Input text should be *black*.
In the case of the web, it's trivial but in the case of native, I don't know how to handle it.

So is that possible at all?

Thanks for any help. Here is the code example

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  TextInput as NativePaperInput,
  withTheme,
} from 'react-native-paper';

import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const NativePaperInputThemed = withTheme(NativePaperInput);

export const TextInputStyled = styled(NativePaperInputThemed)`
    ${(props: any) => {
      return `
        outline: none;  // doesn't work
        input: { outline: none; } // doesn't work
        & input: { outline: none; } // doesn't work
        // Label change style ? 
        color: ${props.theme.theme10x.palette.typography.placeholder}; // doesn't work


        border-color: '#f92a2a8a'; // doesn't work
        height: 52px;
      `;
    }
  }
`;
```

P.S. Basically even colors and fontFamily doesn't work somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some guy tried to change label style manually, the maintainer reponse:

> You can pass fontSize via style prop. However it will affect both
>   label and input text. There is no way to change only one of them.

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1505

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Maycon.
The same about native html input? Also, I'm trying to set the font-family and it doesn't work. Even the color doesn't work. It tells: ` Failed prop type: Invalid ` props.style key `color` supplied to `View`.
Bad object: {
  "color": "#6B767A",
  "borderColor": "'#f92a2a8a'"
}`

Comment: @Velidan On the web i think so :/ But  you can try hard code label via CSS, nesting the TextInput inside a View. My solution was to create my own TextInput component with Label (full styling). You can create on based on this: https://github.com/eyaleizenberg/react-native-floating-label-text-input

Comment: Thank you @Maycon. I'll definitely check this repo.

Comment: This is either an incorrect or outdated answer. You can pass a component for the label prop.

Answer (score 8):

```
label={<Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{t('PersonalDetailsYuvitalOrg:editInput.firstName')}</Text>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a component for the label prop. For Example:

```
export const Input = styled(TextInput).attrs({
   dense: true,
   activeUnderlineColor: theme.colors.ui.blueDark,
   label: <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>My Custom Label</Text>
})`
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   font-size: 16px;
`
```

However, I have not looked for a way to control the scale when the animation occurs.